# Built new kernel, LVM won't mount from initrd

Tags: linux, kernel, rhel, lvm, initrd

I need to upgrade my kernel on a RHEL 5 system to build with some experimental drivers.  I have configured the kernel with module loading for LVM (`dm_*`  modules).  Once the initrd runs the `/init` script, the LVM mounting procedure is failing.

The drives are configured with LVM (including the root device) so during init, it mounts them and performs `switchroot`.

What can I do to understand why `lvmscan` is failing?

Comment: Did you build by calling `make` manually or did you use RHEL's build automation? Did you copy the configuration from the distribution's kernel? Did you rebuild the initrd?

Comment: Latest kernel release candidate.  Using make.  Copied kernel config from distribution, rebuilt initrd.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what the problem was: Red Hat's `mkbldevs` in the init script of the `initrd.img` was failing to make the block devices.  Without any block devices LVM was not able to mount drives.  I installed BusyBox and made a custom initrd and while in the shell I noticed that `mkblkdevs` called by the `/bin/nash` script didn't make `/dev/sd*`.  I suppose you could manually use `mknod` to create the block devices but a search found that a kernel parameter was needed.

This is the kernel parameter:

```
CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED_V2=y
```

You can set it in `.config` manually or browse to in under "General setup" in `make menuconfig`.

I can now boot a variety of kernels that I built.